# How to push a string address into stack using "call" in x86 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, instructions

I want to push a string into stack using `call` instruction in x86 assembly code, but I could not find how to do it. 
Details are as follows:

```
start:
    80484a0: jmp 80484bc
    80484a5: POP %esi
    ...
    80484bc: call 80484a5
    80484c1: .string "hello" 
end:
```

AFAIK `call` instruction put next instruction address into stack in order to return to that address after the call. Thus I expected `esi` should contain the address of string "hello", i.e. 80484c1, but it does not.

`gcc -c -o code code.s` and then
`objdump -D code` prints:

```
...
80484a5: POP %esi
....
80484bc: call 80484a5
80484c1: das
80484c6: jae 8048530 <end+0x66>
80484c8: js  80484ca <end>
....
```

debugging with gdb shows that `esi` equals to `0x80484c1`, which equals to addr of `das` instruction next to the `call`, but it's not the string address I wrote I think. It seems like that assembler converts my code...

How can I avoid this to push the string address? How can `esi` have the address of the string? I even cannot figure out the converted instructions..

Comment: If you want to push something on the stack, you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: As far as I can see, your code is "working as intended". Note that the disassembler can't tell the difference between data and code and has disassembled the string as if it's instructions (which is likely to be confusing you), and that (after that `call` returns) the CPU will do the same (and get confused too).

Comment: First you say, "I expected esi should contain ...  80484c1", then, "gdb shows that esi equals to 0x80484c1". So your question really should be, "Why is there garbage assembly code where I expect my string to be?".  And as Brendan says, when you disassemble a string, you get garbage assembly code.

Comment: Note that this technique messes up the CPU's return address predictor, so it's interesting but not practical.

Comment: @Brendan As many up-voted your comment, I pushed that string explicitly instead of writing ".string xxx" after the `call` in order to know my other code works correctly or not. Pushing string explicitly makes my other code works correctly ("..." portion between `POP` and `call`) but writing ".string xxx" (instead of pushing the string explicitly) causes segmentation fault. So I think my code is not working as intended.